# SQL Distinct not working in query - Why?

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to show 10 unique games that have been played and sort them in tweets. However, when I use **Distinct** it still shows the duplicates in game_id.

As you can see under this picture, you see lots of several game_ids

[image: Lots of different game_ids]

What I am trying:

```
select distinct game_id, spike, _c0 as tweets_per_minute
from virtual4
order by tweets_per_minute desc
limit 10
```

Result:
[image: Result of query above]
**Note:** This table is a view.

Comment: `select distinct` is working fine.  the rows being returned are all different.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: I only want to see unique game_ids in the second picture. I only see duplicates.

Comment: Do you want to see spike & tweets per minute aggregated (summed?) by game_id. So, for example, do you want 21 - 315 - 2948 ?

Comment: In the second picture, I just only want no duplicates in the game_id. That's all I need. :)

Comment: Right, but what do you want to show in the spike & tweets_per_minute columns? Are you looking for multiple rows but to just have game_id show up on the first row OR are you looking for just one row with those other values added up or processed some other way?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Sorry. I just want to show this basically: FROM https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSJ0Z.png TO https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQvXH.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the maximum tweets per game, then `select distinct` is not the right approach.  Try `row_number()`:

```
select game_id, spike, _c0 as tweets_per_minute
from (select v.*,
             row_number() over (partition by game_id order by _c0 desc) as seqnum
      from virtual4 v
     ) v
where seqnum = 1
order by tweets_per_minute desc
limit 10;
```

`select distinct` applies to the entire row, not just to the first column.

Comment: I do not have experience with nested queries. I tried your query but it gives me an error: AnalysisException: unknown table alias 'v'

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you very much for your help and assist.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return distinct rows which are a combination of game_id, spike and tweets_per_minute and then order by tweets_per_minute.

You can try this,

```
select game_id, spike, _c0 as tweets_per_minute
from virtual4
where game_id in (select distinct game_id from virtual4 order by game_id)
limit 10
```

Comment: Your query is exactly what I want (unique game_ids). However the data in my tweets_per_minute are not the same anymore as in the post I've just posted. https://gyazo.com/b9df194531804011ee1df8682069d746

Comment: How do answers like this get upvotes?  The `where` clause does nothing.  `select distinct` is not appropriate when using `in`.  An `order by` is not appropriate in an `in` subquery.  The upvote makes no sense at all.